Change tracking in ADX/Kusto from Graph point of view
We plan to use Graph capabilities of ADX and are looking for guidance. Our scenario is when a vertex (or any of its property) is changed, we want to capture all the related nodes.
Example - Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/graph-match-operator
Pasting here for convenience -
let employees = datatable(name:string, age:long) 
[ 
  "Alice", 32,  
  "Bob", 31,  
  "Eve", 27,  
  "Joe", 29,  
  "Chris", 45, 
  "Alex", 35,
  "Ben", 23,
  "Richard", 39,
]; 
let reports = datatable(employee:string, manager:string) 
[ 
  "Bob", "Alice",  
  "Chris", "Alice",  
  "Eve", "Bob",
  "Ben", "Chris",
  "Joe", "Alice", 
  "Richard", "Bob"
]; 
reports 
| make-graph employee --> manager with employees on name 
| graph-match (alice)<-[reports*1..5]-(employee)
  where alice.name == "Alice" and employee.age < 30
  project employee = employee.name, age = employee.age, reportingPath = reports.manager

In the above example - Imagine 'Bob' is changed 'Bob2', I would like to know all the related nodes too. i.e. His 'manager' all the way to the root (Alice) and his 'reportees' (Eve) all the way to the leaf in the 'change-tracking' system.
This feature is available is CosmosDB-GremlinAPI. Just checking if we can achieve this using ADX/Kusto.

Can you provide your KQL query that you have tried so far?
